# Possible to flatten Vue Apollo cache data structure?

Tags: graphql, nuxt.js, apollo, vue-apollo

I'm working on a Nuxt app with the Vue Apollo module to better learn the GraphQL world.

One major issue I'm running in to is how slow updates to data appears to be - even if I'm using `optimisticResponse` - because of how nested the data is contained within the Apollo Cache.

I'll give an example. On one page, I'm running a query on page load which contains Trips, Categories, Items, and Todos. This is a representation of what my data might look like in the cache:

```graphql
ROOT_QUERY
  trips: [Trip]
    0: Trip:1
      categories: [Category]
        0: Category:1
          items: [Item]
            0: Item:1
            1: Item:2
            2: Item:3
      todos: [Todo]
        0: Todo:1
        1: Todo:2
        2: Todo:3     
    1: Trip:2
```

If I want to say remove one of the items contained within a Category, I would have to run a mutation that would look like this:

```js
async function removeItem ({ fields, trip_id, apollo }) {
  return await apollo.mutate({
    mutation: removeItemMutation,
    variables: fields,
    optimisticResponse: {
      __typename: 'Mutation',
      removeItem: {
        __typename: 'item',
        id: fields.item_id,
        name: '',
        weight: 0,
        unit: '',
        price: 0,
        category_id: fields.category_id,
        quantity: 0,
        position: 0,
        created_at: Date.now(),
        updated_at: Date.now()
      }
    },
    update: (store, { data: { removeItem } }) => {
      // read
      const data = store.readQuery({ query: tripsQuery });

      // mutate
      const trip = data.trips.find(trip => trip.id === trip_id);
      const category = trip.categories.find(category => category.id === fields.category_id);
      remove(category.items, item => item.id === removeItem.id);
      const otherTrips = data.trips.filter(t => t.id !== trip_id);

      // write
      store.writeQuery({
        query: tripsQuery,
        data: {
          packs: [trip, ...otherTrips]
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

This seems extraordinarily verbose for something as simple as removing one item from an array. Currently when I run this (and even with optimisticResponse as I mentioned), there is still a delay of 1-2 seconds. I believe this is because it has to search through all of the nested data in order to find the correct item to remove.

Ultimately what my question is though, is why is the data stored in Apollo Cache in a nested fashion? If it's normalized (which it is), then why wouldn't the data structure be stored flattened, so that I could find that specific Item and remove it, without having to go searching deep within the bowels of multiple nested arrays?

It's extremely possible that I'm over-complicating or over-engineering how this works. Does anyone have a suggestion as to an easier way to handle this, or a way to flatten the data structure that is being stored in the Cache?

**Update:**
I wanted to include a screenshot of what my cache looks like. What I'd really love to do is have the ability to interact with a specific item in that list other than `ROOT_QUERY`.
[image]

Comment: What do you mean that "only `otherTrips` line is required? "Packs" is a typo, I was trying to simplify the code I pasted here and missed that one! It should be `trips`. If I only set `data: { trips: otherTrips }`, then the page empties because it relies on having all Trips available for the page.

Comment: well technically I'd have to remove the item from data.trips[index].categories[index] because it's nested two levels deep, no? `data.trips` reads from the cache correctly, it returns an array of 2 trips, and my page relies on having all trips available. If I only write `otherTrips` back to the cache, then it completely replaces all trips with just that one.

Comment: When I open up the Apollo devtools, I see `ROOT_QUERY` as well as each item separately listed. Is it possible to access those other items, rather than going through the `ROOT_QUERY`? I'll edit my original post with a screenshot to show you what I mean by this.

Comment: ah, nested one ... of course you can remove only nested ... but how rendered? in react it could be a main query (as this) and subqueries within subcomponents (cache-only) for items list ... updating only items array would rerender only this subcomponent (as watching only this cache fragment)

Comment: I have a main page component that calls the query, then I pass the data down to several different components. Technically what I have works (in that it only rerenders what has been updated), but I think because of how nested the data is in the cache, it takes about 1-2 seconds to actually display the update rather than feeling snappy.

Comment: are you sure it works propery? looks like not preserving trips order ... all changed sub-objects should be changed in immutable way - new objects

Comment: Yes, it works. I've been looking at the docs for `readFragment` which appears to be exactly what I'm looking for, just trying to figure out the best way to implement that into a Nuxt project.

Comment: if you pass (drill down) data from main query then fragment (nested subprop) change can be not detected as main query change (no 'main' ref change), not rerendered at all

Comment: log some timestamps... I doubt it (cache update) is a delay reason ... more like updating view problems

Comment: writing fragments would work when 'cache-only' subqueries used

Comment: Everything I'm reading about `readFragment` and `writeFragment` seems like it should be the solution: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v2/caching/cache-interaction/#writequery-and-writefragment

Comment: sure, try ... but don't be suprised it doesn't rerender